# Android:handling backpress on camera intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I am opening camera activity from my app via intent with parameter MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT.Camera is opening but when i backpress without clicking the image my app crashes.I went through similar questions and found camera intent returns null when MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT is used.So how do i check whether image was clicked or not?
Here is the Code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
Uri camCapfileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(camCaptureImageName));
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, camCapfileUri);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, reqCode);

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //Changes camera on backpressed with data null checked
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
        onCaptureImageResult();
    } else if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY && data.getData() != null) {
        onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
    }
}
```

when i checked (data != null)  for camera it worked well in some mobiles and crashes in other mobiles.So how do i handle backpress in this case.

Comment: check Activity.RESULT_CANCELED or Activity.RESULT_OK...in case of back button you will get Activity.RESULT_CANCELED

Comment: Why did you not check RESULT_Ok inside onActivityResult before start using the data or file? If you did not capture or did nothing camera intent its always return the Result_cancel other than that it guaranteed that will return the   RESULT_OK before start extracting the data.

Answer (score 0):

When you set a `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` flag, the `data` will *always* be null (on Android >=5.0 I think).

The proper way to implement it is to maintain an instance of the File which was used as the value to the `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` key in the flag.

Then after clicking the image and getting a `RESULT_OK`, you check whether the File exists.

Please Note: The `File` object may be `null` within `onActivityResult()`. This is because the Activity was recreated when it returned back from the Camera Activity. To solve this, you will need to save the path of the File to the outState Bundle within `onSaveInstanceState()`, and reinitialize it within `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand your problem correctly but you can check if result is ok. I modified your code a little bit.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
Uri camCapfileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(camCaptureImageName));
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, camCapfileUri);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, reqCode);

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //Changes camera on backpressed with data null checked
    // if user press back result will not be RESULT_OK
   if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){ 
      if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
         onCaptureImageResult();
      } else if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY && data.getData() != null) {
        onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
      }
   }
}
```

I hope this'll help you.